# On element click, run code on object with matching attribute value

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<a class="anchor-toggle" data-toggleable="100"></a>
<a class="anchor-toggle" data-toggleable="200"></a>

<div class="modal" data-toggleable="100">
    <iframe src="url"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="modal" data-toggleable="200">
    <iframe src="url"></iframe>
</div>
```

And I have the following jQuery to move the *src* attribute to *data-src* when loading the page (to stop the iframe content being loaded):

```
$('.modal iframe').each(function(){

    var get_src = $(this).attr('src'); // Get src
    $(this).attr('data-src',get_src); // Copy src to data-src
    $(this).removeAttr('src'); // Remove original src

});
```

**Here's what I need to achieve:**

When there is a click on one of the anchor-toggles, I need to find the matching modal (by *data-toggleable* value) and run the following code on it to move *data-src* back to *src*:

```
var get_data_src = $(this).attr('data-src'); // Get data-src
$(this).attr('src',get_data_src); // Copy data-src to src
$(this).removeAttr('data-src'); // Remove data-src
```

Is this possible? Can I somehow combine the objects based on the *data-toggleable* value using .merge() or something similar?

Comment: `var get_data_src = $(this).data("src"); $(this).attr("src", get_data_src); $(this).data("src", "");`

Comment: @Snowmonkey think you misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<iframe src="url"></iframe>` will load the page from the source. Jquery will be loaded after completing the page rendering. And it is useful in many cases. So there is no sense removing `src` after loading it. Best way is not to specify `src` in the html. Try the following example

```js
$(function(){
  $("a.anchor-toggle").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataToggleable = $(this).attr("data-toggleable");
    var iFrame = $(".modal[data-toggleable='"+dataToggleable+"']").find("iframe");
    $(iFrame).attr('src', $(iFrame).attr('data-src'));
  });
})
```

```css
a.anchor-toggle{color: blue; cursor: pointer;}
.modal {display:inline-block;}
.modal iframe{width:200px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <a class="anchor-toggle" data-toggleable="100">1st</a>
    <a class="anchor-toggle" data-toggleable="200">2nd</a>
</div>
<div class="modal" data-toggleable="100">
    <iframe data-src="http://www.stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="modal" data-toggleable="200">
    <iframe data-src="http://www.stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, except replace `.children` with `.find` to account for a deeper structure (my code was simplified from code generated by the framework I use)

Comment: Ok nice, iframe was the first child in your code. Thats why `.children` filter used. Thats more efficient than `.find` for child filteration. If the posted code was simplified one and the your iframe lies inside some element, then `.find` is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".anchor-toggle").click(function(){
    var data_toggleable = $(this).attr('data-toggleable');
    var iframe = $("div[data-toggleable='"+data_toggleable+"']").children('iframe');
    var get_data_src = iframe.attr('data-src'); // Get data-src
    iframe.attr('src',get_data_src); // Copy data-src to src
    iframe.removeAttr('data-src');
})
```